# Jmeter run : Java heap space error : out of memory error

Tags: jmeter, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I'm getting the following error:

> out of memory error : java heap space error while running jmeter script for long run say 20 hrs.

I have set 10 GB heap size to run 10 threads only.

Could it be my application's bug? How can I be sure that this is application's  bug not a jmeter issue?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter is a Java application with a GUI. It also supports a non-GUI mode which is *less* resource intensive(CPU/RAM). If we run JMeter in non-GUI mode, it will consume less resource and we can run more threads.

- Disable ALL Listeners during the Test Run. They are only for debugging and use them to design the desired script.

Listeners should be disabled during load tests. Enabling them causes additional overheads, which consume valuable resources that are needed by more important elements of your test.

- Use Up-to-Date Software:

Java and JMeter should be kept updated.

- Decide Which Metrics You Need to Store:

When it comes to storing requests and response headers, assertion results and response data can consume a lot of memory! So it is wise try not to store these values on JMeter unless it’s absolutely necessary.

**JMeter SaveService badly configured**: Check if you are saving requests and responses in your JTL.

For better and more elaborated understanding, this blog about [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/nine-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) is helpful.